# How to get my code to check if it contains all specified characters

Tags: javascript

Hi there im new to coding and im trying to get this code to work. What I need to do is to make sure that all the text entered by the user contains all the characters that I've specified in the array and if it does alert true if not alert false. Im struggling if you could help that would be great.

```
var userinput = prompt('Input characters:');

var lowercase = userinput.toLowerCase();

alert(lowercase);

var allowedcharacters = [abcdef];

if (lowercase == allowedcharacters){
  alert(true);
}
else{
  alert(false);
}
```

Comment: Didn't you post your question already in another Thread?  
So what exactly do you mean? Shall all these characters be inside the user input? Are different ones allowed? Please specify

Comment: Sorry I changed the code slightly and didnt know how to change it in the post so I thought Id how to create a new thread. I want to make sure all these characters are inside the user input. If they are it needs to return true and if not return false

Comment: Your declaration of allowedcharacters = [abcded] is actually not correct. If you want an array of multiple characters you would have to write = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, according to your comment you need something like this:

```
function checkWord(sInput, arAllowedWrds) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arAllowedWrds.length; i++) {
        if (sInput.indexOf(arAllowedWrds[i]) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

You would then copy this function to your code and call it like this:

```
if (checkWord(lowercase, allowedcharacters)) {
    alert("True");
}
else {
    alert("False");
}
```

Please mark the answers as correct if they solved your problem, so the thread gets closed.

Cheers,
Florian

P.S.:
Your declaration of `var allowedcharacters = [abcded]` is actually not correct. If you want an array of multiple characters you would have to write `= ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
if (/[^a-f]/i.test(input))
    // Waaah!
```

Comment: This regex just checks if none of the characters a-f are in your input (if I am not completely wrong, excuse me in case I am)